# how do you adjust the residuals of a linear mixed model?

Tags: r, statistics

I’m having issues collecting the data I need for a power calculation which will be performed by someone else. My stats and coding abilities are minimal so could really use some help!

**Experimental set up:** male and female subjects ***(=sex, M/F)*** from 2 different groups ***(=genotype, WT/KO)***. I need to know how many subjects and how many samples/subject I need to analyse. I already analysed 2 subjects for each condition, 20 samples/subject, which provides the dataset I'm using for the power calculation.

I’m currently using a linear mixed model analysis, such as:

```
logdendritemeandiameter.lm <- lmer(log(Dendrite_Mean_Diameter) ~ 
        sex + genotype + (1|subject), data = dendrite)
```

**Problem:** I have been requested to “save the residuals adjusted for sex, standardise them and send mean and SD in KO group and in the WT group separately." For various reason, this it the best explanation of what I have to do I can get.

**Question:** I have standardised my residual using:

```
stres = residuals(logdendritemeandiameter.lm, type = "pearson")
```

However, I cannot understand how to **adjust the residuals for sex** and how to then **obtain mean and SD for each of the genotypes separately**. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things I don't understand about this question, but I'll try to help.

- it's **extremely** dicey on statistical grounds to use part of the data set to calculate power for how many more samples you need to take.  You should do a power analysis *a priori* based on (1) expected [or minimal interesting] effect size; (2) ideas based on previous experiments or on common sense of the magnitudes of the error terms (among-subject variance, residual variance)
- I'm not sure what "save the residuals adjusted for sex, standardise them and send mean and SD in KO group and in the WT group separately". It sounds like someone *might* (?) want you to fit the model accounting only for sex, not for genotype (which has levels `WT` (wildtype) or `KO` (knockout)?):

  ```
  newmod <- update(model_with_a_long_name, . ~ . -genotype)
  r <- residuals(newmod)
  aggregate(r, by=dendrite$genotype, "mean")
  aggregate(r, by=dendrite$genotype, "sd")
  ```

I would recommend going back to whoever told you to "standardise the residuals" and ask them for clarification about what they actually meant ...

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the quick reply and the code. Literature is extremely variable when it comes to sample size for this kind of analysis and the knock-out I'm studying hasn't been characterised before (let alone the effect of sex on it) so it was hard to know what to expect apriori. The difference between groups is visually obvious and highly significant (p<2.2e-16 for all combinations) in the current dataset, but it can take up to a month to analyse a subject and I've been asked to increase to n=5 subjects for each group - so I was hoping to be able to reduce the n of samples/subject.